# How can I receive (void *)0x12345678 argument?

Tags: c, unix, xv6

In test.c (user level)

```
tid = thread_create(thread, (void *)0x12345678, stack);
```

I want to receive arguments of above thread_create function. So, I wrote code in sysproc.c (kernel level)

```
if(argptr(0, (void*)&function, sizeof(*function)) ||
   argptr(1, (void*)&arg, sizeof(*arg)) ||
   argptr(2, (void*)&stack, sizeof(*stack)))
    return -1;
```

but, only the second line caused error. How can I change the code of this part??

> argptr(1, (void*)&arg, sizeof(*arg))

I am working on xv6 os, and original defined function is

```
int thread_create(void *(*function)(void*), void *arg, void *stack);
```

and test.c cannot be chaged.

Comment: if `arg` is of type `void*` then  `sizeof(*arg)` implies looking for `sizeof(void)` which I don't think is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

We don't see the declaration of `arg`, but it seems it's `void* arg`, so, your code should be:

```
argptr(1, (void*)&arg, sizeof(arg))
```

I am not a language lawyer, so I don't know is `sizeof(void)` valid from a languages standard point of view, but most C compilers I used give `1` for it. C++ compilers usually report an error. In any case, it's not what you want here, you want `sizeof(void*)`